# Open Office automation fails when executed from Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, automation, iis-6, openoffice.org

I'm using this guide as a basis for what I'm doing:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/generatepdf.aspx?fid=1517061&select=2903150&fr=1#xx2903150xx

I am using the Open Office CLI bridge to try to create an ASP Generic Handler that will download a file from an MS SQL database, convert it to a PDF, and send it back to the browser or app that requested it.

Here's what I've tried:

- The Service shown in that article (including adding the OO.org 3 fixes).
- Moving the relevant code directly into the Web Service and Switched IIS to run the 32bit .Net runtime (required for OO.org).
- Creating a command line tool that performs the conversion and then spawning a process that runs the tool and waits for the Exit code (0 = success, 100 = failure a, 200 = failure b, so on and so forth)

So far all of these work when debugging the code using the development ASP server that Visual Studio provides.  What doesn't work is deploying it to my development server and trying to run it there.  I can get processes to run no problem, including OpenOffice's soffice.exe and soffice.bin, but under none of those circumstances does the conversion actually occur.  I've tried giving the IIS service the ability to interact with the shell and trying to run the process under my own credentials (works under VS's ASP.net server but not on my dev server) but neither was fruitful.

This has been rather frustrating to be so close yet so... far.  Any help figuring this one out would be appreciated.  My guess is there's some IIS/ASP.net configuration option that I'm missing.  My development and production environments use VS2008 and IIS6 under Windows XP 64bit.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 0):

Have you actually installed OpenOffice on your production machine. I know that sounds big, but I have had a similar issue when dealing with MS Office. Regardless of whether I copied the appropriate files across they weren't registered.

Hence installing MS Office solved the issue. However I am sure if you register the appropriate files it would work as well. Maybe as a quick test deploy it on a machine without Open Office installed and see if it works, then install Open Office and see if

Comment: OO.org has to be installed on the system via the software's Installer for Automation on Windows.  Reason being if the DLLs necessary for automation aren't in the GAC it doesn't work well.  There is a portable version of OO.org that people try to automate but I think newer versions don't play well with that technique.

I'm also passing it the command line args to not pop up the registration window but that doesn't seem to work either.